# Getting multi result from sql result and put into foreach query , got Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

```
$con=mysqli_connect($localhost,$username,$password,'db');

$query = 'SELECT  `SN` FROM `list` WHERE `Floor` LIKE "LP60" AND `type`LIKE "pc"';
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error());

foreach ($result as $SN)
{             
    $get = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM pc WHERE pcSN LIKE '.$SN.'ORDER BY EvenID DESC LIMIT 1')

            while ($get_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                echo '<tr>'; // printing table row
                echo '<td id="ID">'.$get_row[0].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$get_row[1].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$get_row[2].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$get_row[3].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$get_row[4].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$get_row[5].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$get_row[6].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$get_row[7].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$get_row[8].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$get_row[9].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$get_row[10].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$get_row[11].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$get_row[12].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$get_row[13].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$get_row[14].'</td>';
                echo'</tr>'; // closing table row

                }
}
```

I have tested both query are working fine, have tested to print_r($SN) as well
but at the end i got Array to string conversion error, any help please

I have found the solution by using

```
'" . mysqli_escape_string($con,$SN) . "'
```

and now the new code like this

```
$con=mysqli_connect($localhost,$username,$password,'db');

// mysql select query
$query = 'SELECT  `SN` FROM `list` WHERE `Floor` LIKE "LP60" AND `type`LIKE "pc"';
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
foreach ($row as $SN){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pc WHERE pcSN LIKE '" . mysqli_escape_string($con,$SN) . "' ORDER BY EvenID DESC LIMIT 1";
    $get = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                while ($get_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                    echo '<tr>'; // printing table row
                    echo '<td>'.$get_row['xxx'].'</td>';
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
                    echo '<td>'.$get_row['yyy'].'</td>';
                    echo'</tr>'; // closing table row

}
}
}
```

Thanks everyone has been helping me here, i think  add up all little bit to made it worls.
Thanks
Wish this post can help any other as well

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to access the values in an associative array using numeric indexes. Use the column names instead. `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns an associative array.

Instead of this,

```
$get_row[1]
```

Try to use this,

```
$get_row['column_name']
```

**Edit**

As per your comment about still getting an error try to add a space between `$SN` and the next concatenation `ORDER`. This might be causing your problem since when you echo out the sql statement you have no space there.

This,

```
...LIKE ArrayORDER BY...
```

Should have been,

```
...LIKE Array ORDER BY...
```

So change your statement,

```
'SELECT * FROM pc WHERE pcSN LIKE '.$SN.'ORDER BY EvenID DESC LIMIT 1'
```

by adding a space to,

```
'SELECT * FROM pc WHERE pcSN LIKE '.$SN.' ORDER BY EvenID DESC LIMIT 1'
```

Comment: i have changed to each column name but problem remain.
When i echo the mysqli_query out and it will show like this

"SELECT * FROM pc WHERE pcSN LIKE ArrayORDER BY EvenID DESC LIMIT 1"

But when i print_r($SN) and var_dump($SN), both can show the individual SN

Comment: Hey , i have edited my answer to provide a possible solution. Take a look below the edit word.

Comment: unfortunately the Array to string conversion error still remain

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
while ($get_sn_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $SN = $get_sn_row['SN'];
   $get = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM pc WHERE pcSN LIKE '.$SN.'ORDER BY EvenID DESC LIMIT 1');

   while ($get_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) {
        ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
$get=mysqli_fetch_assoc...
```

Use

```
$get=mysqli_fetch_array...
```

Then you'll be able to get the data like this:

```
echo $get[0];
```